# Proof solutions linear congruence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, congruences

If $x_0$ is the solution of the system of linear congruence equations:
$$ x \equiv c_1 \text{ mod } m_1$$
$$ x \equiv c_2 \text{ mod } m_2$$
$$ \cdots $$
$$ x \equiv c_s \text{ mod } m_s$$

AND the $\gcd(m_i, m_j) = 1 \forall i \neq j$.

Show that the set of solutions is: $X = \{x_0 + k \cdot m_1 \cdot m_2 \cdot \cdots \cdot m_s \text{ with } k\in \mathbb{Z}\} $.

It makes totally sense to me...but how can I show it mathematically correct?
Has anyone a hint for me?

Comment: What is $x_0$? $\space$

Comment: $x_0$ is the "first" solution of the system of linear congruence equations.

Comment: Does the Chinese remainder theorem sound familiar to you?

Comment: Of course! 
Using the chinese remainder theorem I can actually calculate $x_0$.
And I also know that x_0 is ONE solution of the system and there is an endless number of solutions, represented by the set of solutions described above.

But how can I prove that?